# Рандомная смена ссылки при обновлении страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Необходимо, чтобы ссылка менялась при каждом обновлении страницы. Я попробовал реализовать это так, но не получилось:

Есть код:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/random.js"></script>
        <a href="/fon-picture-priroda" id="rek_left_block">
            <div class="but_rek_left_block" id="but_rek_left_block">
                <div><spans>Открыть сайт</spans></div>
            </div>
        </a>
```

И `JS`:

```
var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var RandElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr.length))];

if (RandElement == 1) {
    document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'http://google.com/'
} else if {RandElement == 2) {
    document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'vk.com'
} else if (RandElement == 3) {
    document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'som.com'
}
```

Но ссылка не меняется.

Answer (score 2):

У вас там опечатка в строке `{RandElement == 2)`

Скобку замените на `(`

Comment: Спасибо, но не в этом проблема была.. все равно не работает

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сами ссылки сложить в массив:

```js
var links = ['https://google.com/', 'https://vk.com', '//som.com'];
var link = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length)];
document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = link;
```

```css
a:after { content: attr(href) }
```

```html
<a id=rek_left_block></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

В примере ошибка в открывающей скобке в `{RandElement == 2)`, после ее исправления все работает:

```js
var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var RandElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length))];

if (RandElement == 1) {
  document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'http://google.com/'
} else if (RandElement == 2) {
  document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'vk.com'
} else if (RandElement == 3) {
  document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'som.com'
}
```

```html
<a href="/fon-picture-priroda" id="rek_left_block">
  <div class="but_rek_left_block" id="but_rek_left_block">
    <div>
      <spans>Открыть сайт</spans>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Как по мне, в подобных случаях удобнее использовать switch case.

```js
var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var RandElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
var link = '';
console.log(RandElement);
switch (RandElement) {
  case 1:
    link = 'http://google.com/';
    break;
  case 2:
    link = 'http://vk.com/';
    break;
  case 3:
    link = 'http://som.com/';
    break;
}
document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = link;
```

```html
<a href="/fon-picture-priroda" id="rek_left_block">
  <div class="but_rek_left_block" id="but_rek_left_block">
    <div>
      <spans>Открыть сайт</spans>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Ошибку исправил, ваш вариант попробовал, почему-то не работает.. ссылка так и остается на "/fon-picture-priroda"

Comment: @user250973 видимо, неправильно копируете код. Дополнил ответ с исправлениями в вашем коде.

Comment: Не работает все равно.. Вот более полный код. По сути, мне надо поменять и "текст", но сначала надо бы с ссылкой разобраться, почему она не меняется https://jsfiddle.net/LLveeyk5/

Comment: @user250973 в вашем коде все работает. Как вы проверяете?

Comment: обновляю страницу, где эта ссылка и смотрю изменилась ли она

Comment: Понял.. скрипт надо было подключать после кода html, а не до

Answer (score 0):

У вас ошибки по коду. Вот так работает:

```
var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var RandElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr.length))];

if (RandElement == 1) {
document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'http://google.com/';
} else if (RandElement == 2) {
document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'vk.com';
} else if (RandElement == 3) {
document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'som.com';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arr = new Array(1, 2, 3);
var RandElement = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*(arr.length))];

if (RandElement == 1) {
    document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'http://google.com/'
} else if (RandElement == 2) {
    document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'http://vk.com'
} else if (RandElement == 3) {
    document.getElementById('rek_left_block').href = 'http://som.com'
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="/javascript/random.js"></script>
        <a href="/fon-picture-priroda" id="rek_left_block">
            <div class="but_rek_left_block" id="but_rek_left_block">
                <div><spans>Открыть сайт</spans></div>
            </div>
        </a>
```