# Как сократить код не изменяя сути?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код:

```
 var arr = new Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30);
var RandElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
var link = '';
console.log(RandElement);
```

И `swith`:

```
    switch (RandElement) {
  case 0:
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('left_block_menu'),
        SummSumm='текст';
        SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;  
  break;
  case 1:
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('left_block_menu'),
        SummSumm='текст';
        SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;
  break;
...
```

И всё выполняется отлично, рандомное число определяется и взависимости от него выдается тот или иной текст. Но есть ещё кнопка, при нажатии на которую число должно увеличится на один и выдать результат без обновления страницы (с учётом изменившегося числа, т.е. если был `case3`, то после нажатия текст должен браться из `case4`. У меня получилось это сделать только так:

```
    document.querySelector('.but_rek_left_block3').onclick = function() {    
    RandElement++;
    if (RandElement == 31) {
    RandElement = 0;
    }
    console.log(RandElement); 
    switch (RandElement) {
  case 0:
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('left_block_menu'),
        SummSumm='текст';
        SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;  
  break;
  case 1:
    var SummDok = document.getElementById('left_block_menu'),
        SummSumm='текст';
        SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;
  break;
...
```

Но это увеличение кода, поскольку и так `swith` на 30, и в кнопке тоже.. может есть способ всё это сократить?

Вот `div` (кнопка):

```
<div class="but_rek_left_block3" id="but_rek_left_block3">
    <div><spans>Пропустить</spans></div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/707619/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy, предлагаешь дубликатом жахнуть?

Comment: А зачем нужен arr, если используется только его длина и зачем switch, если case в нем выполняют одинаковые действия

Comment: Пишите как удобнее. Что тут сокращать то?

Comment: @Hipster ye 30 кейстов в switch-е, конечно же это надо переписывать как в примере предоставленом Qwertiy

Comment: @Grundy, ну формально это не дубликат, но мне отвечать второй раз лень.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял задачу и должно подставиться в див просто число - то вот код:

```
var caces = 30;
var SummDok = document.getElementById('left_block_menu');    
var RandElement = Math.round(- 0.5 + Math.random() * (caces + 1));

function insertValue(){
    SummDok.innerHTML = RandElement; 
}

insertValue();

document.querySelector('.but_rek_left_block3').onclick = function() {
    RandElement +=1;
    if (RandElement === 31) {
        RandElement = 0;
    }
    insertValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот возможное решение. https://jsbin.com/naxelijoro/5/edit?html,js,output

html:

```
<div id="left_block_menu"></div>
<div class="but_rek_left_block3" id="but_rek_left_block3">
     <div><span>Пропустить</span></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
function insertSumm(RandElement){
  var SummSumm = '';
  var SummDok = document.getElementById('left_block_menu');
  switch (RandElement) {
    case 0:   
        SummSumm='текст0';
        break;
    case 1:
        SummSumm='текст1';
        break;
    case 2:
        SummSumm='текст2';
        break;
  }
  SummDok.innerHTML = SummSumm;
}

window.onload = function(){
  //здесь переменной length присвоено 2 для примера
  //вы можете поставить 30 и соответственно расширить функцию insertSumm
  var length = 2;
  var RandElement = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  insertSumm(RandElement);
  var button = document.getElementById('but_rek_left_block3');
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){
    RandElement++;
    if(RandElement > length){
      RandElement = 0;
    }
    insertSumm(RandElement);
  });
};
```

Лучше было бы конечно, если бы вы пояснили что меняется в зависимости от того какое число попадает в инструкцию switch. Тогда вероятно можно было бы устранить эту страшную конструкцию в 30 кейсов!